# Simple code of express library of node.js not working

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
app.listen(8000);
var tweets = [];
app.get('/', function(req,res){
res.send('Welcome to Node Twitter');
});
app.post('/send', express.bodyParser(), function(req,res){
if(req.body && req.body.tweet) {
    tweets.push (req.body.tweet)    
}
})
```

This simple code not working. Showing Segmentation Fault..
express version: 2.3.10
node.js version: 0.4.2

.I cant work in other versions . have to work in these only.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Have you tried on a more recent version of Node? `0.4.2` is pretty old.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

then do your post like this:

```
app.post('/send', function(req,res){
  if(req.body && req.body.tweet) {
    tweets.push (req.body.tweet)    
  }
});
```